# JavaScript difference between console.log(string.length); and console.log([string.length]);

Tags: javascript

The section of code is

```
var string = ['one','two','three'];
console.log(string.length-1);
console.log([string.length-1]);
```

Output:

```
3
[ 3 ]
```

Can anyone tell me why my output is like this in the second scenario.It is a JavaScript code.

Comment: `[string.length]` creates an array with one value.

Comment: Because you are printing array in second scenario..

Comment: Read about [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets returns an array. Array definition like this : var arr = [1,2,3];

In your scenario console.log(**[string.length-1]**);